# I am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace/remove the first hyphenand 3 subsequent characters

Tags: regex, oracle

I am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace/remove the first hyphen and 3 subsequent characters. Input table is not of fixed length and varies. I am trying to come up with a working express that will

```
5F9B9C7F-ABC-40F4
CODE-AXF 2014 CODE
ADSHLHSALK
```

Expected results results should be

```
5F9B9C7F-ABC-40F4   ==> 5F9B9C7F-40F4
CODE-AXF-2014 CODE  ==> CODE- 2014 CODE
ADSHLHSALK          ==> ADSHLHSALK
```

Query:

```
SELECT text, column   
REGEXP_REPLACE( text,'[-]',NULL )
FROM TABLE
where column=  '5';
```

Comment: The `CODE- 2014 CODE` should actually be `CODE 2014 CODE`. You say you need to remove the hyphen together with 3 subsequent chars.

Comment: What if your input contains a hyphen, followed by fewer than 3 characters? Such as  `INTRO-28` ? Do you still want to remove the hyphen and the two (or one or zero) characters right at the end? Or is that guaranteed not to happen in your strings (not today, and not two years from now when the query will still be running in production)?

Comment: mathguy is right.  I have some entrie such as INTRO-28XXX.  In this instance, I want to keep the hyphen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('5F9B9C7F-ABC-40F4','^([^-]*)-.{3}','\1')
```

If you mean 3 *letters*, then replace `.` with `[a-zA-Z]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `([^-]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `.{3}` - any 3 chars (or `[a-zA-Z]{3}` will match 3 ASCII letters).

See an [online demo](http://rextester.com/ORNEM61083) printing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions:

```
SELECT text,
       column,
       SUBSTR( text, 1, pos - 1 ) || SUBSTR( text, pos + 4 )
FROM   (
  SELECT text,
         column,
         INSTR( text, '-' ) AS pos
  FROM   TABLE
  WHERE  column = '5'
);
```

Comment: See my comment under the original question though. This solution will output `INTRO` from the input `INTRO-28` - even though there aren't three characters after the dash.

Comment: @mathguy that is simple enough to solve with a `CASE` statement checking whether the hyphen is in the last 3 characters and then returning the original string in that case, if it will exist. Regular expressions are still not necessary.